# $. template returns an object instead of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, anonymous-function, jquery-templates

I'm using a jQuery plugin called the [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) by BorisMoore.

Everything works perfectly on the **main page**, but when I browse the **contact page** the plugin does not work:

### Error message in chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
jquery.tmpl.js:329

Uncaught Template command not found: getDay 
js:2000
```

### I registered my tags as follows:

```
var blogMarckuptmpl = '<li>' + '<div class="blog-date">' + '<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/calendar.png")" alt="Calendário" />' + '<span class="blog-dateDay">{{getDay publishedDate}}</span>' + '<span class="blog-dateMonth">{{getMonthName publishedDate}}</span> ' + '</div> ' + '<div class="blog-text">' + '<a href="{{=link}}" target="_blank" title="{{=title}}">' + '<h4>{{=title}}</h4>' + '</a>' + '<p>{{=contentSnippet}}</p>' + '</div>' + '</li>';
$.template("blogTmpl", blogMarckuptmpl);
$.views.registerTags({
  getDay: function(val) {
    return new Date(val).getDate();
  },
  getMonthName: function(val) {
    return new Date(val).toString("MMM").toLowerCase();
  }
});
var feedBlog = new google.feeds.Feed("http://blog.bindsolution.com/rss");
feedBlog.setNumEntries(4);
return feedBlog.load(function(blogFeedResult) {
  if (!blogFeedResult.error) {
    $("#blog-feed").html($.render(blogFeedResult.feed.entries, "blogTmpl"));
  }
}
```

Browsing the source JsRender found that on the **contact page** in `$.template(tmpl)` function returns an object instead of a anonymous function (as in the main page).

### More Information

To facilitate understanding, captured images of the debug chrome:

Two images for each page (contact page and home page)
The first image (with final [1](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender)) is the debug before `$.template(tmpl)`, the second (ending [2](http://imgur.com/a/LwXDn)) with the debug after the `$.template(tmpl)`.

**Note the `tmpl` object  in Scope Variable (right side)**

**Home Page (before)** : `tmpl` string type

**Home Page (After)** :
Note the `tmpl` object  in Scope Variable (right side)
He is an anonymous function! (Correct!)

**Contact Page (before)** : `tmpl` string type

**Contact Page (After)** :
Note the `tmpl` object  in Scope Variable (right side)
`tmpl` is a object type !!??

** Debug Images **

Also available at: http://imgur.com/a/LwXDn

**Home Page (Before)**

[image: Home page (before)]

`tmpl` string type

---

**Home Page (After)**

[image: Home page (after)]

Note the `tmpl` object  in Scope Variable (right side)
He is an anonymous function! (Correct!)

---

**Contact Page (Begore)**

[image: Contatc page (before)]

`tmpl` string type

---

**Contact Page (After)**

[image: Contact page (after)]

Note the `tmpl` object  in Scope Variable (right side)

`tmpl` is a object type !!??

Comment: What's calling that "render" function?.

Comment: Also, what's in that object that's returned?

Comment: JsRende believe.

But I managed to solve the problem. I'll post the resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Talking to the creator of the plugin I discovered that it does not work side by side with jQuery templates.

Follow the conversation:
https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/19